# Issue with Slate Js Mention example while integerating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, slate.js

Referring to the Slate.js mention example,
https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/main/site/examples/mentions.tsx
I want to integrate it with my React app.While integration facing issue with hooks used in the code..

QueryComponent.js

```
const QueryBoxComponent = () => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>()
    const [target, setTarget] = useState<Range | undefined>()
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
    const renderElement = useCallback(props => <Element {...props} />, [])
    const editor = useMemo(
      () => withMentions(withReact(withHistory(createEditor()))),
   []
   )

   const chars = CHARACTERS.filter((c) =>
    c.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())
      ).slice(0, 10);
```

I am calling it as a functional component:

```
    <div className="stockfilterresult" style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
            <QueryBoxComponent />
    </div>
```

[image: Error image]

```
 const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>();                                             ^
  35 | const [target, setTarget] = useState<Range | undefined>();
  36 |   const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  37 |   const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

 BabelLoaderError: SyntaxError: 
   C:/Users/HP/Downloads/StockUI/src/components/QueryBoxComponent.jsx: Unexpected token (34:44)
```

> ```
> 34 |   const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It uses Typescript and your error looks like you don't have TypeScript installed.